# Laravel 5.4: Erro ao criar tabela - unexpected '(', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'

Tags: laravel, artisan

Ao executar o comando *php artisan migrate* para criar a tabela no banco, aparece o erro abaixo:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'
```

Parece ser um erro de sintaxe, porém não consigo ver onde está o erro, já criei outras tabelas, incluindo as que são chaves estrangeiras dessa sem problema nenhum.

Minha migration está assim:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateConvServsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('conv_servs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('id_convenio')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('id_especialidade')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('id_convenio')->references('id')->('convenios')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('id_especialidade')->references('id')->('especialidades')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('conv_servs');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isto parece errado:

```
$table->foreign('id_convenio')->references('id')->('convenios')->onDelete('cascade');
$table->foreign('id_especialidade')->references('id')->('especialidades')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Não tem muito sentido `->('convenios')->` e `->('especialidades')->`, tenho certeza que deveriam ser funções.

Comment: Segundo a documentação do Laravel, aí nesse lugar é onde vai o nome da tabela que eu to referenciando. Já criei desse jeito outras tabelas com chaves estrangeiras e funcionou normalmente.

Comment: Cara, não acredito que esqueci do ON antes do nome da tabela. Meus Deus velho. Que erro estúpido.

Comment: @DiegoVieira se é programação acredite sempre cometeremos erros estupidos :) ... é como eu com portugues, é uma gafe atras da outra XD, pode marcar a resposta como aceita?

Answer (score 1):

Esqueci de colocar o "ON" antes do nome da tabela. Segue o código arrumado:

```
Schema::create('conv_servs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('id_convenio')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('id_especialidade')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('id_convenio')->references('id')->on('convenios')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('id_especialidade')->references('id')->on('especialidades')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```